# Why &(&i)is not valid in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i;
i=0;
printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", i, &i, &(&i));
return 0;
}
```

i think that &i is just a value of address, and assume that it's 0xFF so &(&i)should be the address of 0xFF but why it's not valid?

Comment: What is the address of 0xFF?

Comment: ..because it makes less sense than Mourinho taking over at Man U.

Comment: I meant that 0xFF is also a constant, so there should be a constant that refers to the address of the constant '0xFF'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unary `&` operator need an lvalue as its operand and returns an rvalue. `&i` is an rvalue, therefore `&i` can't be an operand of `&`.

Comment: Would 
address of a variable considered as constant ?

Comment: @ameyCU; Yes, it is.

Comment: Thnx a lot! I got it perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

> 6.5.3.2.
>
> 1. The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
>    [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
>    not declared with the register storage-class specifier.

`&i` is an address of an object.

This means that unary `&`cannot be used on `&i`, as the address doesn't designate an object or a function, nor is the result of `[]` or `*` operator.

Your example is effectively: `&0`, and constant `0` obviously doesn't fall on the above list.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse addresses and pointers.An address is an rvalue.You can't apply the "address of"(&) operator on it.Pointers however are objects.They are lvalue-s and can be the operand of '&'.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, look at it this way. You got a bee nest. In a square I put some honey. Using the & operator you refer to that square. Using again the & operator you refer to the square in which the square is located, you can`t do that.

More precisely &i refer to the memory location is i. You can`t refer to the memory location of a memory location.